# Does a question count as a personal question if a normal Christian would not ask such a question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, close-reasons, pastoral-advice-questions

The question in question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59662/what-are-the-general-guidelines-on-amening

My question was put on hold as off-topic.

> "Questions seeking pastoral advice are off-topic here; your spiritual problems are too important to be left in the hands of random Internet people. See: Why can't I ask for personal advice?"

In the question I asked about **general guidelines** on "amening." For example, "How long does it take for an amened message to reach God?"

Although I worded the question to make it applicable to many Christians, it is not so. **Pretty much nobody else would ask such a question.** Who doesn't know the correct term for "amening," whatever that means (I don't, so amost nobody else understands my question)?

**If I'm the only person who would ask a question** (even if the questions are general)**, does that question count as a personal question?**

Comment: I voted as unclear. It does not seem to be a real question.

Comment: As I'm not sure what a normal Christian is, I am unable to be of any help in this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I myself don't see that there is a correlation between it being a “personal question” and it being a question that only one person in the world would ask.  Indeed, it often seems that I have many thoughts and concerns which never grace the minds or consciences of other people.  (I believe someone once wrote something lamenting such a predicament.)  Those thoughts are no less important — to me, at least — for their seeming uniqueness.

(One person, abnormal Christian, whatever.)

Your example question could've probably been reopened if you asked for guidance researching a specific, published doctrine.  I'd expect that some could say the prayer is heard instantly, and that the form is less important than the intent; others could say that it is through the format of the prayer, rather than the reception, that we gain the most benefit, and therefore that it does matter; yet others could say that it would be heard, but sin or disingenuity would serve to muddle it anyways; indeed, some could say all of those things and more.

Probably one of the reasons why people develop so many sects is because they are dealing with a Being that is far too large to be comprehended in the human mind.  Unfortunately, many people similarly confuse the Church with the more apparent aspects of it, and thence comes the sectarianism …